# Is one annotation better than the other for mypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting, mypy

Consider the following two annotations:

```py
def foo1(arg: tuple[datetime, int] | tuple[datetime, None]) -> datetime:
    ...

def foo2(arg: tuple[datetime, int | None]) -> datetime:
    ...
```

**Is there a reason to use one over the other?** *(besides preference)*

As far as I can tell they are logically equivalent; are they?

Comment: Technically the same. The only reason I'd use the second option to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) the code - say you'd decide to support `date`s instead of `datetime` - only need to change once.

Answer (score 2):

The two are not *exactly* equivalent.

It would be invalid to pass a `tuple[datetime, int | None]` to the first variant, but valid for the second.

Given

```
def foo1(arg: tuple[datetime, int] | tuple[datetime, None]) -> datetime:
    ...

def foo2(arg: tuple[datetime, int | None]) -> datetime:
    ...
```

the code

```
x: tuple[datetime, int | None] = ...

foo1(x)
foo2(x)
```

fails type checking with mypy with the message

```
error: Argument 1 to "foo1" has incompatible type "tuple[datetime, int | None]"; expected "tuple[datetime, int] | tuple[datetime, None]"  [arg-type]
```

Whether that is useful depends on your use case.

Comment: Good point. But isn't this a mypy's issue?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych No, it is not. It's not generally true that `C[T | S]` is compatible with `C[T] | C[S]`. It's more obvious if you consider something like `C=Sequence`.

Comment: interesting. What version of mypy are you getting that error for `foo1`?  I tried in 1.4.1 and didn't get errors either way.

Comment: @MarcelWilson It looks like 1.4.1 does emit an error: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.4.1&python=3.11&gist=f6ee0e9207f1587f438e9826d3a7711e

Comment: Ooops.. had `strict_optional=False` configured.

Comment: I'm glad you pointed this out.  "mypy is looking at the shape of the cookie cutter not the cookies that get made"

Answer (score 1):

As Brian pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76923124/14401160), for some `C` generic in one type it is not guaranteed that `C[T | S]` is compatible with `C[T] | C[S]` for any `T`, `S`.

However, this affects not only all external callers, but also implementation itself. Consider the following snippet:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def foo1(arg: tuple[datetime, int] | tuple[datetime, None]) -> None:
    if arg[1] is None:
        reveal_type(arg)  # N: Revealed type is "tuple[datetime.datetime, None]"
    else:
        reveal_type(arg)  # N: Revealed type is "tuple[datetime.datetime, builtins.int]"

def foo2(arg: tuple[datetime, int | None]) -> None:
    if arg[1] is None:
        reveal_type(arg)  # N: Revealed type is "tuple[datetime.datetime, Union[builtins.int, None]]"
    else:
        reveal_type(arg)  # N: Revealed type is "tuple[datetime.datetime, Union[builtins.int, None]]"

x: tuple[datetime, int | None]

foo1(x)  # E: Argument 1 to "foo1" has incompatible type "tuple[datetime, int | None]"; expected "tuple[datetime, int] | tuple[datetime, None]"  [arg-type]
foo2(x)
```

Note how the type gets narrowed in two functions.

In the former case, you know that the argument is of type `tuple[datetime, int]` OR `tuple[datetime, None]`. So, if it's last item is `None`, you can really narrow the type to `tuple[datetime, None]` only, and it happens.

In the latter, the type remains the same, though formally such narrowing would be safe (if I don't miss anything). Same `is None` check does not narrow `tuple[datetime, int | None]` to `tuple[datetime, None]`. This implementation is consistent in `mypy` and `pyright`, so there may be deeper reasons why the type is not narrowed in the union case.

[Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.4.1&python=3.11&gist=0f7c15dd78c3e08e73aba28d43911049)